# New Enterprise Org, New Sandbox: No Login As, no 'Organization Admins Can Login as Any User'

Tags: lightning, sandbox

I have a brand new Enterprise org. It is all set to lightning. I created 2 admin licenses and then created a sandbox.

I created another user in the sandbox to let him see the new system. This user is a System admin.

The user I created in Production does allow me to "login as" but this new one doesn't AND he sees Salesforce Classic, not Lightning. I went to the Security|Login Access Policies but the checkbox isn't there.

(We already have an existing org and that has 2 months to go so I don't want to create the user in Production)

What's going on?

Comment: Did you enable lightning in the sandbox? Setup--> Lightning Experience --> Lightning Experience ( all way at the bottom) is it enabled?

Comment: For login as the best way is to create delegate groups, check if the delegate group is created in PRD (or) the user in context has modify all permission and the admin is granted access by the user to login as the user: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0 (or)

Comment: Lightning is enabled

Comment: I don't have an org of a size to need delegated authority. This doesn't answer my need to login as a user.

Comment: does the user not see a drop down to select "Switch to lightning experience" from the setup? if not se under lighting experience "Decide Who Can Use Lightning Experience" switch the users default setting to be lighting.

Comment: @Rao It is set to be the default. (also: user lives in Australia while I am in the USA, so I cannot get to them right now)

Comment: Are you a sys admin (or) someone with View Setup and Configuration in the sandbox, I ask this because you should be able to set the "Administrators Can Log in as Any User" in your sandbox? From your question, i see that you do not see this option am i right?

Comment: I am the admin but the checkbox just isn't there.

Comment: Looks like this is a feature that you need to request: https://www.shellblack.com/administration/login-as-any-user-without-having-to-grant-access/